# Currently working on a project, I get the outcome but it's not the outcome that I was expecting

Tags: python

Alright, so I am currently working on a project where I have a pouch containing 9 balls. Three balls are green, three are red and three are blue. The goal is to take out a ball (at random), then another, and then another and then the program is supposed to "re-do" itself over and over again to show how likelihood and favorable outcome is connected to possible outcome.

Then repeat the process 10 times for 100, 1000 and 10 000 "pulls". 
The code I have written is as follows:

```
import random

picked_balls = []
pouch_temp = []
counter_equal_balls = 0
amount_pulls = 100
pouch_original = ["Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red"]
respons = input("Write 'Start' to pull your three balls: ")
correct_respons = "Start"
combined_likelihood= 0


def pull_ball_from_pouch(picked_balls, pouch_temp):
    for i in range(3):
        picked_ballsindex = random.randint(0,
                                             len(pouch_temp) - 1)
        picked_balls.append(pouch_temp[
                                  picked_ballsindex])
        del pouch_temp[picked_ballsindex]
    return picked_balls

while respons != correct_respons:
    respons = input("Write Start: ")

for x in range(10):
    for i in range(amount_pulls):
        pouch_temp = pouch_original.copy()
        picked_balls = []
        picked_balls = pull_ball_from_pouch(picked_balls,
                                            pouch_temp)
        if picked_balls[0] == picked_balls[1] == picked_balls[
            2]:
            counter_equal_balls = counter_equal_balls + 1
    likelihood_to_pull_equal = (
                                           counter_equal_balls / amount_pulls) * 100
    combined_likelihood = (
                                         combined_likelihood + likelihood_to_pull_equal) / 10
print("Result: " + str(combined_likelihood) + "%")
```

Now to the real problem: When the "re-dos" are done 10 times what it does is it takes the ten results, puts them all together and then divides them by 10. Is there a way for the program not to pile them up and instead gives us a "real" percentage that varies 10 times?

I'd appreciate it a lot if I could get some answers to what I am doing wrong, feels like I've hit a wall. Very active so I will respond to any and all answers :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be kind enough to reduce you code snippet to a __minimal__ [mcve] ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what combined_likelihood is but assuming my knowledge is correct, what you are trying to do is :

likelihood_to_pull_equal = Number of times out of 100 that 3 different balls were picked.

combined_likelihood is then: For each "redo" what is the accumulated probability? If so then the error is based in how you define combined_likelihood.

From your code, you are ONLY printing the last calculation. You should probably put combined_likelihood into a list and append to it in your loop. So each time in the for loop, your combined likelihood is stored rather than just printing the last one as you are doing now.

So I would guess:

```
holder = [] #somewhere above
#your code
holder.append(combined_likelihood)#after you calculate it a the same indentation level.
print(n)#should show all your combined likelihood.
```

If this is still not correct, then there's something wrong with how you calculate your combined likelihood. You might want to fix your combined likelihood equation if that is incorrect because it looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this refactoring, it is lacking the user input. It fills a result dictionary for every iteration. It then fills an array with all the results.

```py
import random
pouch_original = ["Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red"]
def grab(balls, number_of_iterations):
    total_result = []
    #total result will be filled with 1 result on every iteration
    for x in range(number_of_iterations):
        #print the current iteration
        print("iteration " + str(x + 1))
        #copy over the contents of the original pouch so we can use it
        temp_pouch = balls.copy()
        #initialise the dictionary with the counters set to 0
        results = {
        "Blue": 0,
        "Green": 0,
        "Red": 0}
        #grab 3 times
        for x in range(3):
            #generate a random index based on the amount of items left in the pouch, this is why we need a temp pouch
            random_index = random.randrange(0, (len(temp_pouch)))
             #the corrosponding counter is updated
            results[temp_pouch[random_index]] += 1     
            print("picked: " + temp_pouch[random_index])
            #and the ball is removed from the pouch
            temp_pouch.pop(random_index)
        #print the results of this iteration    
        print(results)
        #and append them to the array of results
        total_result.append(results)
    return total_result

result = grab(pouch_original, 10)
print(result)
```

You can then iterate trough the result array and do some math, or you could do some math in the grab function. Experiment away !